# Best cloud based DB solution for Matlab / Running Python Code from Matlab

Tags: database, mongodb, matlab, amazon-dynamodb, containers

I'm searching for the best possible cloud based database solution, which can be accessed via Matlab. In the best case I could store higher level variables, e.g., cells and query items within them with a fuzzy  search. Maybe there is the possibility to query such a DB with python code from Matlab?

MongoDB and Cassandra can be accessed via the DB toolbox of Matlab but don't allow for querying within container variables as far as I know. DynamoDB and DocumentDB can't store such variables as far as I know. There also maybe a go-to solution that I dont know about or just couldn't think of myself.
(Also the pricing isn't very transparent as well)

Maybe someone has an idea or experience with this kind of problem?

Thank you very much in advance,
Leo

Comment: `but don't allow for querring within container variables as far as I know.` what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean querring for a certain string within multiple texts within an uploaded cell variable. An example would be: Search for all texts that contain "Hello" in the cell variable "Greetings" in cell 1,2 (which is a string array with dimensions 5x10000 for example).